# Images display on device but not on emulator? Android

Tags: android, image, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3

In part of my app I check for screen density using:

```
float sdpi = ApplicationConstants.ref_currentActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
if(sdpi == 0.75)
    {
        ApplicationConstants.screenSize = "small";
    }
    else if(sdpi == 1.0)
    {
        ApplicationConstants.screenSize = "medium";
    }
    else if(sdpi == 1.5)
    {
        //Message.inform("Setting Screen Size", "sdpi is:" + sdpi + " so screen size is large");
        ApplicationConstants.screenSize = "large";
    }
    else if(sdpi == 2.0)
    {
        ApplicationConstants.screenSize = "xlarge";
    }
```

and then later on in another part I simply have a method that loads the right image bitmap, based on the screenSize:

```
   if(ApplicationConstants.screenSize.equals("small"))
    {
        imageName = imageName + "s";
    }
    else if(ApplicationConstants.screenSize.equals("medium"))
    {
        imageName = imageName + "m";
    }
    else if (ApplicationConstants.screenSize.equals("large"))
    {
        imageName = imageName + "l";
        //Message.inform("ImageName should have an l at the end", imageName );
    }
    else imageName = imageName + "x";
```

So basically - if im calling findImageByName("SomeImage"),
Then the image name will change based on the screen density to SomeImages(small), SomeImagem(medium), SomeImagel(large), SomeImagex(xlarge) - 
and then I use imageName to create a drawable out of the image I extract from a jar file.

I see this works FINE on my mdpi screen device - but on the emulator I have no images showing up where they are supposed to.

I thought maybe I just made a silly mistake somewhere, so I changed ApplicationConstants.screenSize to be "medium" even when my sdpi is 1.5, and still not images load on the emulator run.

Anyone ever had this problem?

Note: The reason I am loading images this way is because it is a modularImageLoader class, that loads images from a jar file. The jar file contains images required for a .class I load dynamically at runtime with a DexClassLoader . If anyone has any questions about the process of dynammic module loading - please feel free to ask, and I will explain why I load images the way I do.

Any help is appreciated :) fellow StackOverflowers.

Note: I do not currently have access to a hdpi-real life android device.Otherwise I would have tested there to see if it works.

**EDIT:**

I've managed to make it work on the emulator - but this is without using states... which I will eventually need to use on the buttons to make sure they look like they are being clicked.

**Here's what works:**

b[i].setBackgroundDrawable(ApplicationConstants.moduleImageLoader.findImageByName(drawable_normal));

**and here's what doesn't work: but should!**

states.addState(new int[] {},              ApplicationConstants.moduleImageLoader.findImageByName(drawable_normal));
b[i].setBackgroundDrawable(states);

b is an array of buttons.
ApplicationConstants.modularImageLoader gets the correct imageLoader for the current module. 
findImageByName takes an "imageName" appends s,m,l,x based on the screen density and returns the drawable matching that name (that is an image file with that name in the jar that is my module).
ModularImage loader works hand in hand with my module Loader - making sure to load the right imageLoader for its corresponding module.

Any idea why states don't work in this scenario? any help is appreciated... Am I using states incorrectly?

Comment: +1 for the note at the end. I was thinking "WHY WHY WHY" the whole time till I got there. :)

Comment: @kcoppock - Yea! I had a feeling I'd get a lot of comments saying "Why on earth would you do that..." - so I added the note.

Comment: @ all - Also it seems that its a problem with the state list drawable for button backgrounds. Even when I set all the states to use the same drawable, it wont draw the first time. Touching the area where the button is, or switching back to the screen make icons show up. Any ideas, my friends? You guys are awesome. Also if required I'll post up my code on state lists.

Answer (score 1):

Unless those are typos, I think your most likely problem is assuming that density corresponds to screen size. In reality, it's most likely going to be the inverse of what you've coded (e.g. the higher the density, the smaller the screen size -- typically) since the larger the screen, the further the pixels are spread, leading to a lower density. Of course, the screen resolution can be increased to compensate and make a higher density, but in most cases a higher density is more likely to be a smaller screen than a screen with a lower density.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by typos. sdpi is a variable that returns the density of the screen - according to android docs - 0.75 corresponds to ldpi screens [hence the word small], 1.0 corresponds to mdpi, hence the word medium and so on and so forth. Besides, if there was an issue with there being a typo, it wouldn't work on the device either.

Comment: Also i'm only using small, medium etc, to tell me which images to load - for ldpi small, i'd load an image that is 36x36, for mdpi, medium, id load an image that is 48x48 and so on. When I say small,medium etc, im referring to bitmaps for screens, not the screen size itself. I hope this makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Well, you just have your variable named `ApplicationConstants.screenSize`, so I kind of assumed you were thinking that the DPI correlated to the screen size. If you mean that to just specify the image, then okay. The variable name just seems a bit misleading. :)

Comment: Sorry about that then - I guess its a little confusing. ApplicationConstants. "anything" helps me keep track of some variables that I need in my activities - since I'm doing dynammic module loading in my application. Thanks for the input!

Comment: +1 - for pointing out I wasn't clear. It's probably one of the most required skills for askers on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are multiple possibilities, for example:

- path to the image is different in the emulator
- image does not exist in the emulator
- not enough memory to load the image (try smaller size or change the memory settings per the emulator)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but it doesn't seem to be any of these cases.